# How to centralise application properties outside project structure in mule 4

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a requirement to keep all property file outside project in mule 4. I would appreciate any help regarding this. If there is any way to access property files from outside.

I was trying zuul reffering to this link. But there is no support for this now. It was last updated in 2014. Also it is not running in latest tomcat version.

https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-meets-zuul-centralized-properties-management-part-1/

I don't want to keep property file in resources folder. Please suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

The blog mentioned is for Mule 3 so while the concepts might be valid the implementation is not compatible for Mule 4.

Some people that want to externalize properties files just references properties files by absolute path in a directory outside the Mule installation directory.

Another option in Mule 4 you can create a [custom properties provider](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/custom-configuration-properties-provider) and implement in Java any access to Zuul or some other way to collect the properties. You have to find how to configure the property backend you select and how to access it using Java code.